# Hook mmap/munmap without LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, hook, mmap, libc

I would like to hook to mmap and munmap, typically called inside libc in memory allocator functions. One way to do is LD_PRELOAD -- is there anyway to do this programmatically ? Note that I want to hook to the mmap/munmap inside libc, not one from my application.

Comment: On linux, use `ptrace`...

Answer (score 4):

`LD_PRELOAD` can only redirect function calls inside glibc for a small set of functions related to the allocator (`malloc`, `free`, and so on).  System calls in particular are often inlined, so that there is no function call involved at all. As Antti Haapala said, use `ptrace`, or you can also [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) or a manually written kernel module.

Answer (score 2):

> is there anyway to do this programmatically?

There is, but it's not pretty.

You can scan the `.text` of `libc.so.6`, looking for `CALL __mmap` instructions, that is: `0xE8` (or other `CALL` opcodes) followed by 4 bytes that equal to delta between the next instruction and `__mmap`.

Once you found such instruction, you can `mprotect` the page to be writable, patch it to `CALL` a different routine, and `mprotect` it back.

There are a few downsides:

1. This is a *gross* hack.
2. You better ensure there are no threads running concurrently while you are patching.
3. You better ensure that you don't call `malloc` (or anything else that can call the code you are currently patching) while you are patching.
4. False positives are possible (a byte sequence that looks like a `CALL` may not actually be a `CALL`). In my expirience this never happened.
5. In a 64-bit process, your target routine may be farther away from the `CALL` then the `+/-2GiB` offset you can stuff into the `CALL` instruction itself. Solving this requires another gross hack (`CALL`ing to a trampoline, which you can establish within a sufficiently long sequence of `NOP`s within `libc.so.6` itself; the trampoline can perform a `JMP` to arbitrary address).

Did I mention this isn't pretty?

Another alternative is to build your own `libc.so.6`, with the `__mmap` and `__munmap` routines exposed via PLT. The patch to do this is quite small, but this only works if you can depend on using your own GLIBC build everywhere you run.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. You can always set an alternate environment, either with env or with putenv(), then execute the target program. Similarly, you can add a breakpoint to a process using gdb.

Why don't you describe your real task ?